# If $p$ is a second order polynomial we have the following information about. What is $p (-3)$? The answer must be an integer.

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials

> If $p$ is a second order polynomial we have the following information about:
>   $p (0) = 3$, $p '(0) = 8$ and $p' '(11) = 8$.
>   What is $p(-3)$? The answer must be an integer.

I am doing calculus, but I am completely lost and can't find any answers in the book. (We've gone through limits, continuation and differentation)

Answer (score 2):

You have $$p(x) = ax^2+bx+c$$ then your constraints are
$$
3 = p(0) = c \\
8 = p'(0) = b \\
8 = p''(11) = 2a
$$
Can you solve from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ then  $p'(x)=2ax+b$ and $p''(x)=2a$. Hence
$$p(0)=c=3\;,\; p'(0)=b=8\;, \; p''(11)=2a=8.$$
Are you able to evaluate $p(-3)=9a-3b+c$ now?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a generic second-order polynomial, p(x)=ax<sup>2</sup>+bx+c. What is p'(x) and p''(x)?

p''(x)= 2a = 8, so a=4. p'(x)=2ax+b, so what is b?

Answer (score 0):

Say that your polynomial is of the form
\begin{equation}
p(x)=ax^2+bx+c.
\end{equation}
where the values $a,b,c\in R$.
Then we know that
\begin{equation}
p'(x)=2ax+b.
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
p''(x)=2a.
\end{equation}
Therefore we can impose the values given as
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
p(0)=3\mbox{ gives } c=3\\
p'(0)=8\mbox{ gives } b=8\\
p''(11)=8\mbox{ gives } 2a=8\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
solving the system gives you the values of $a,b,c$ for a polynomial satisfying the given conditions. Those values are evidently $c=3$, $b=8$ and $a=4$. Then just evaluate
\begin{equation}
p(-3)= 4(-3)^2+8*(-3)+3=15.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ \color{#0a0}{\deg p(x) \le 2}\ \Rightarrow\ p(x)\, =\, p(0)\, +\, p'(0)\, x\, +\, \large{\frac{p''(\color{#c00}a)}2}\, x^2\ $ for *any* $\,\color{#c00}a\in \Bbb R\ $ (by $\,\color{#0a0}{p''\in \Bbb R})$

Comment: i.e.  simply apply  **Taylor's expansion** using $\,p''(0) = p''(\color{#c00}{11})\,$ since $\,p''$ is constant when $\,\deg p \le 2\ \ $